# pandas Serie idxmax() fails when dtype is dtype('O')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I believe a change with a recent version causes the call to idxmax() to fail in this case where it used to work before. I am not saying it is a regression, I'm trying to understand the reason and the correct call to issue.

```
type(sss)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
sss.dtype
dtype('O')
type(sss.index)
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
sss.index=Index([...strings.., dtype'object', length=112)
```

The single column in the serie has number type with many NaN, and some valid numbers.
All indices are strings.
I am searching for the index of the maximum of the column.

How can I obtain that?

Comment: Should better dtype be assigned to the index and the single column?

Comment: For reference, what is your pandas version?

Comment: the version is 0.22.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't replicate on pandas 0.19.2. You can convert to `float` and then use `pd.Series.idxmax`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1.5, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, 54, 19, np.nan]}, dtype=object,
                  index=list('abcdefgh'))

res = df['A'].astype(float).idxmax()  # 'f'
```

Answer (score 1):

### Option One

```
s.index[np.argmax(s.tolist())]
```

---

### Option Two

```
max(s.index, key=s.get)
```

---

## Numeric Demo

```
s = pd.Series([0, 8, 4, 3], list('WXYZ'), object)

s

W    0
X    8
Y    4
Z    3
dtype: object
```

---

```
s.index[np.argmax(s.tolist())]

'X'
```

---

```
max(s.index, key=s.get)

'X'
```

---

## String Demo

```
s = pd.Series(list('5Z4A'), list('ABCD'), object)

s

A    5
B    Z
C    4
D    A
dtype: object
```

---

```
s.index[np.argmax(s.tolist())]

'B'
```

---

```
max(s.index, key=s.get)

'B'
```